# Azure search get starts with data from query

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search, startswith

I am using azure search in my project.I just want to show only starts with query data in my autocomplete field.Example ; when user writes 'advert' on the autocomplete field it also shows 'Addresable Advertising' as suggestion.Here is my code below :

```
 var response = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<Model>
            (s+"*", new SearchParameters() { Top = size, Skip = page * size, Filter = "IsVerified eq true" });
```

Comment: Hey, happy to help. I don't understand what is the problem you are experiencing. Please provide a sample query and expected results. This post explains how to do prefix search with Azure Search: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9bd165f1-6ed2-40b5-9819-dd709c79fd20/wildcard-search-queries-like-startswith-contains-and-endswith?forum=azuresearch

Comment: This post helped me , thanks a lot !